# Rails has_many through association delete path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `place` model and a `user` model and a `user_place` model, `user_place` belongs to `user` and `place` both. Traditional has_many through association.

I have a page where you can view the users associated with a place.  My routes look like:

```
  resources :places do
    resources :user_places
  end
```

which generates these routes:

```
place_user_places GET    /places/:place_id/user_places(.:format)                                                  user_places#index
                                      POST   /places/:place_id/user_places(.:format)                                                  user_places#create
                 new_place_user_place GET    /places/:place_id/user_places/new(.:format)                                              user_places#new
                edit_place_user_place GET    /places/:place_id/user_places/:id/edit(.:format)                                         user_places#edit
                     place_user_place GET    /places/:place_id/user_places/:id(.:format)                                              user_places#show
                                      PATCH  /places/:place_id/user_places/:id(.:format)                                              user_places#update
                                      PUT    /places/:place_id/user_places/:id(.:format)                                              user_places#update
                                      DELETE /places/:place_id/user_places/:id(.:format)
```

I don't love this but I'm ok with it for now.

But whenever I try to delete a `user_place` I have all sorts of issues.

```
<%= link_to "delete", place_user_place_url(place_id: @user_place.place_id, id: @user_place.id), method: 'delete' %>
```

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_places", :id=>nil, :place_id=>2}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
```

I had this working previously with slightly different routes and an actual form:

```
  resources :places do
    resources :user_places, as: 'user', only: %i[index create new]
    delete 'remove_user', to: 'user_places#remove_user'
  end
```

```
            <% if user != current_user %>
              <%= form_with model: @user_place, url: place_remove_user_path(@place.id), method: 'delete' do |form| %>
                <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, value: user.id %>
                <%= form.hidden_field :place_id, value: @place.id %>
                <%= form.submit  "delete" %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

But this feels hacky, I don't think I should need a specific form, and this was leading the form to be submitted with javascript which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be a solution is to [use shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) in the routes (**shallow: true**).

```rb
resources :places do
 resources :user_places, shallow: true
end
```

Make sure to run `rails routes` again. The delete method of a user_place will no longer be nested.

You can then simply delete the user_place passing a single variable (an instance of a user place, @user_place). There is no need to set the id (place_id or id) as Rails is smart enough to handle that. Just passing an instance variable is enough for the delete method to find the corresponding record.

```
<%= link_to "delete", user_place_url(@user_place), method: 'delete' %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to simplify it a bit but I'm not exactly sure where the `@user_place` comes from, I'm looking at a list of all users associated with the place so we have a `@place` param, and a `@place` has many `@users` but I will need to create a helper method to get the `UserPlace.where(user_id: @user, place_id: @place)` which feels a little less than optimal.

Comment: It depends on which page you want to display the delete link. You could define the relationship with a user in the index method of the places controllers.
```ruby
def index
 place = Place.find(params[:id)
 @user_places = place.users
end
```

In your view, you can iterate over all the @user_places. In this case, use user_place instead of @user_place.

```ruby
 @user_places.each do |user_place|
 <%= link_to "delete", user_place_url(user_place), method: 'delete' %>
end
```